# Migrating content from sitecore 7.2

Tags: webapi, migration

So we need to migrate content from sitecore 7.2 to sitecore 8. But it's not only migrating, we also need to modify the content in order to have updated content in the new instance. 
Our original approach was like: 
Old Site -> JS tool -> worksheets  ....   Updated(modified) worksheets -> JS Tool (as a webpage) -> New sitecore

We though about using item web api, but, is there any other way to pull the data? even if we can do a dump of the data or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of approaches people have taken to accomplish such a task. One of my preferences is to use the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) module. With some knowledge of PowerShell, you can just about do anything with the content.

#### Option 1 : Sitecore Item Web API

Use whatever method available to you, such as the Item Web API. With SPE or vanilla PowerShell you can consume the data, transform, and then import. SPE also includes a Web API but you completely customize what data is returned and how it's formatted.

#### Option 2 : SPE Import/Export Wizards

There is a *Data Import Wizard* bundled with SPE that would allow you to import updated content where the data is in CSV format.

[image: Wizard Screen 1]

[image: Wizard Output]

One way to get started is by creating your own report and then using the export feature. You may find it helpful to reference media items using the GUID and export those separately. The [book](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/authoring-reports.html) provides many examples on how to get started.

Reports have an export option at the top left.

[image: Example Report]

Check out the **#module-spe** channel on the [Sitecore Slack Chat](https://sitecorechat.slack.com/) to have more detailed discussions.

#### Option 3 : [SPE Web API](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/web-api.html)

Write a custom script to return data in any format you like. This could include converting images to base64 and restructuring data into a new format designed to match the destination environment. Then write another script to import the data into the destination system.

Comment: Oh thanks, Im gonna take a look at it. Just a question, by report, what do you mean?

Comment: SPE has a built-in integration which is generated when using the command `Show-ListView`. Essentially it's a way to display data returned by `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`. The reporting section in the book provides examples at how to get started. The export buttons are there by default.

Answer (score 1):

Another option your could use is Content Migrator: https://jeffdarchuk.com/2016/10/24/sitecore-sidekick-content-migrator/

[image]

This is part of Sidekick which you can download here and it looks like it's supported on Sitecore 7.1 and above: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Sidekick.aspx

You can also install it from NPM like so:

```
Install-Package SitecoreSidekickContentMigrator -Version 1.4.2
```

The github page is here: https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/SitecoreSidekick

Once you've installed it and configured it you should be able to pull content from your 7.2 to your 8 instance.

I've written a few blog posts on using it here:

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/simple-sitecore-content-synchronisation-with-sitecore-content-migrator/

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/upgrading-sitecore-content-migrator-and-scheduling-content-syncs/

In terms of updating the content you would need to write some scripts with Powershell or C# to update it afterwards as Sidekick/Content Migrator can't do that for you unfortunately.

Also I can across this post that you may find useful for info on Migrating content with Powershell:

https://medium.com/sitecore-tips-tricks/migrating-large-amounts-of-content-in-sitecore-fb35a488cba